# Extrude along the specified path

Tags: extrude, 3d-cursor

In this image, the extruding action is done along those two blue lines that cross the 3D cursor, how did it do this?[image]

Comment: Assuming you have the faces selected, Alt-E > Extrude Faces along Normals?

Comment: Yes, of course directly extruded with the E shortcut
You can also watch this educational video from the link below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Abtnju3ttHM
He designs this part from the eighth minute onwards

Comment: @yasin1364 You cannot see it in your screenshot because he is already doing the extrusion, so the top menu bar is not visible. He has set the _Transform Pivot Point_ to _Individual Origins_.